# Custom stackoverflow settings

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

Is it possible to be able to set some default settings, such as the display format of dates of posts? (For example, I would much rather see *2011-13-01* than the current *jan 13 '11*)

In addition to an alternative datetime format one could also think of some other settings, perhaps some color blind settings, light/dark-theme or some other stuff I'm sure some clever people here can think of.

Comment: You may want to browse http://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts to see if there is anything there you want to use. (Or you could write your own!). StackOverflow / StackExchange sites have enough work to do already though without having to manage individual user preferences too.

Comment: For color-blind people, I think the right approach would be to ensure the default theme is adequate (which isn't totally the case, there is at least another question on this precise topic). It's much simpler to ensure no point in an interface rely only on colors to be readable than to manage a set of themes.

Comment: Related (re the date formatting) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82156/allow-users-to-set-custom-date-formats

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, please do not overcomplicate things with endless little settings to suit each and every user.

You can style and tweak Stack Overflow endlessly in your own browser.

- There are Stylish plugins for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/?src=external-userstyleshome), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe), [Safari](http://sobolev.us/stylish/) and [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/stylish-for-opera/), with several [Stack Overflow themes](http://userstyles.org/styles/browse/all/stack%20overflow) to choose from already. It is easy to create your own styles.
- For altering behaviour, you can add [Greasemonkey to Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) and [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/violent-monkey/?display=en) or [NinjaKit to Safari](https://github.com/os0x/NinjaKit); Chrome supports most such scripts out-of-the-box. Then head over to [UserScripts.org](http://userscripts.org/scripts/search?q=stack+overflow&submit=Search) to find yourself Stack Overflow tweaks.

Many of these styles and scripts are also (or only) featured on [StackApps.com](https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts), the Stack Exchange Q&A site for the SE API, SE applications and scripts.

Comment: I hadn't heard of clien-side styling before. I'll give this try, thanks

Comment: For Chrome, there's also [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)

Comment: @JanDvorak: It's a script manager, I believe. It doesn't add any additional userscript compatibility, does it?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Ah, it adds `GM_*` and `@useragent` support.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I had one script refused by chrome but accepted by Tampermonkey. No idea why it failed of if it's consistent behavior or just a hiccup. I've never tested since.

Comment: @MartijnPieters TIL `GM_` is available in Tampermonkey. Thanks for letting me know.