# Respect user's prefered-color-scheme setting on the Stack Exchange network to allow dark mode

Tags: feature-request, design

**The reason that answers on the linked post do not answer this question:**

**NONE of them address the use of the user's prefers-color-scheme setting which is the root and CLEAR difference between this question and why it is worth asking.**

Original question:

Now that a majority of users in the world (currently over 75%, per: https://caniuse.com/#feat=prefers-color-scheme) have the ability to have the browser identify if the user prefers light or dark color scheme, how about having the Stack Exchange network respect that? It's actually an accessibility issue for many users as well as power saving for mobile devices to respect the user's preference for a dark theme.

Comment: That clearly doesn't answer my question, I read that and made sure that I was asking another question!!!!!

Comment: If you don't believe this is a duplicate please edit your question to make it clearer how they are different and that will likely help it get reopened.

Comment: Also see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326028/why-not-make-a-dark-theme-instead-of-time-travel-joke

Comment: We can't respect the color scheme request in browsers if we don't have a dark theme... if we ever were to create a dark theme, we likely would be able to meet your request but ... there is no dark theme, so there's nothing we can do here until that existed. Perhaps your best bet would be to write an answer to the linked question to add your specific need - "when the dark theme exists, please have it respect browser settings to prefer light or dark themes".

Comment: The closing of the original clearly told me to post another question if I thought it should not have been closed... That's what I did and everyone freaked out!!! It is clearly not a duplicate already, there is no way to edit io make it less duplicate!!!!

Comment: Someone suggested I add a very clear section to the question explaining why this is not a duplicate rather than editing the question to not be a duplicate which doesn't make sense, I have done so. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Where does that query say that the value is actually set to dark? It contains values for light & no-preference as well, doesn't it?

Comment: The duplicate is fine as it also has [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333768/158100) which is similar to what you address. The man point remains: The CSS system for SE sites don't support user based color schemes, whether you call it dark/ grey or green doesn't matter.

Comment: Related on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386150/should-stack-overflow-revisit-the-dark-mode-question-in-light-of-new-situations

Comment: @rene - clearly that first answer is not a duplicate and does not address the meat of my question - it never even references the prefers-color-scheme media query...

Comment: however that second answer does address the issue briefly. I edited that to include the updated info from my question that was not found in any of the other questions that user's said were duplicate.

Comment: Just because a question has some info that is similar does not make it a duplicate...I wish people could figure that out.

Comment: This has been discussed and denied: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326028/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172818/282094 - I can't add new duplicates to the list in the banner, but I can add them here in a comment.

Comment: I've personally implemented a dark theme for multiple apps and it isn't that hard... Yes, you would have to evaluate every color choice. However, with the user's help in a beta mode or something similar we could very easily get it done.

Comment: @Catija Maybe you should have one light theme for each site and a dark theme with text that's simply the name of the site. Sort of like on the bottom bar but at the top.

Comment: I used title case in the title intentionally and rolled it back as it was not correct, title case is for titles... see https://titlecaseconverter.com/rules/ if you have questions.

Comment: If you look at question titles here, in general, we do not use title case.