# If my post is clearly not a duplicate but users keep closing it as duplicate what am I supposed to do?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

[Respect User's prefers-color-scheme Setting on StackExchange Network to allow dark mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341807/respect-users-prefers-color-scheme-setting-on-stackexchange-network-to-allow-da)

I've already edited it before posting to make sure it is not a duplicate and users are mistaking it as a duplicate because it has the phrase dark mode in it.

How am I supposed to make it clear that a relevant question that may have some similarity to an existing question, is not a duplicate?

Comment: Not really, I tried to make sure my question was clearly marked as not a duplicate in the text and someone closed that question instead.

Comment: For future reference, it might have been better to ask why this was judged a duplicate (or explained why it's not) as a learning experience for others who might encounter similar issues, but the accusatory tone, I'm afraid the voting will simply fall to whether you're assertion is correct (or not). Just trying to help.

Comment: What accusatory tone? My question was closed within minutes without me ever commenting...

Comment: @DrCord _"I tried to make sure my question was clearly marked as not a duplicate in the text and someone closed that question instead."_ To be precise, you didn't put any efforts in editing your original question to clarify, but deleted it and asked a new one instead. The new question also didn't contain any explanation why the marked duplicate didn't contain the answer for your feature request already.

Comment: That original question boils down to *support dark mode* and the answer is *that is not supported* which is an answer available on the duplicate. If an answer on the dupe does answer the question, duplicate closure is preferred.

Comment: `[it's] clearly not a duplicate but zealous admins keep closing it [anyway]`. It's not really the seeds of a productive discussion. Just trying to help folks who may encounter similar problems going forward.

Comment: That's exactly what the site told me to do!!!!
quote:
Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.

Closed 1 hour ago by Glorfindel feature-request .

Comment: Why don't the answers in that dupe don't resolve your question?

Comment: I'm trying to get help against what I see as an attack when there is no clear way to do so from the question, so I posted exactly what was happening in this question to figure out what I am supposed to do... Now you are telling me you cannot help because you don't like how I worded it...

Comment: I went back and made it  very clear why the answer that are in the non-duplicate question do not resolve/answer my question.

Comment: @DrCord You should calm a bit down regarding what you're receiving as _personal attacks_. We're just curating about good and useful content for future research. Non of the SE sites is meant as a personal help desk for you.

Comment: META is supposed to be able to ask a question and get feedback about it, not get it closed with no ability to get help for it.

Comment: I've never thought about StackExchange as a personal help desk for me, having helped many, many people on the network, I have no idea why you would think that about me.

Comment: @DrCord Cite: _"I'm trying to get help against what I see as an attack"_

Comment: I've edited this post to tone the vitriol back a few notches and to focus on what you're actually asking. For future reference, this is more along the lines of how a constructive question should be asked (note the lack of accusatory statements). This may help to change the trend in downvoting as a nice side-benefit.

Comment: Your question *is* a duplicate. [This comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341807/respect-users-prefers-color-scheme-setting-on-stackexchange-network-to-allow-da#comment1143633_341807) very clearly indicates why (they can't respect the user's preference because there is no dark theme). I don't understand what the question is.

Answer (score 12):

> I've already edited it before posting to make sure it is not a duplicate and zealous admins are not reading

There is nothing wrong with our reading abilities.

> but close it because it has the phrase dark mode in it...

Yes, isn't that you're asking? Support Dark mode, either by the site or by browsers / extensions.

> What am I supposed to do to actually ask a relevant question that may have some similarity to an existing question but is certainly not a duplicate?

Explain with an edit what makes that your dark mode support request is much different from all we has before and why it is beneficial for SE to implement your suggestion instead of what was proposed earlier.

It is unfortunate that the post notices got so much improved that they now offer confusing advice. You are not supposed to re-ask the same question over and over again, despite that the post notice seems to instruct you so.

Note that if the answers found on a duplicate question apply to your question as well, they are still considered to be duplicate. In this specific case that seems to be "support dark mode" where the answer still is "Not yet".

Once substantially edited, the question goes into the re-open queue where fresh eyes re-evaluate the closure.

There is a chance users make mistakes here, that seems to be part of human nature.

Comment: Thank you for clearly responding to this. I have done the suggested things and hope my question is able to be moved back into active status.

Comment: Also, the site told me to repost the question instead of editing it...

Comment: QUOTE: Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.

Comment: @DrCord Honestly, that is a flaw with post notices that needs to be fixed IMO. I've had multiple people be confused about it. In reality, editing should almost always be your first step when dealing with a potential duplicate, and very rarely is asking a new question warranted.