# Should we search in answers too, to avoid asking a question about that same matter?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, search, duplicate-questions

Can asking a question that has an answer in another question result in being duplicate?

For example, imagine someone wants to ask if the recipe in [this website](https://www.chicagotribune.com/travel/ct-kfc-recipe-revealed-20160818-story.html) is really original or not.

He tries to ask, but none of suggested questions tend to ask this exact question.

But there's an [answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/73432/89518) that is speaking about the same matter he wants to ask.

Comment: This would probably vary between sites.

Comment: Relevant discussion: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356135/776523

Comment: Yes, you should absolutely search in answers too. The point of the dupe system is to get people to the *answers that solve their problem*, the question doesn't have to be an exact match.

Comment: Not the best example, but: "Note that if the answers found on a duplicate question apply to your question as well, they are still considered to be duplicate.". Source: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341814/282094 --- Note that a question (here, on MSE) can be a duplicate even if it has no answers; and an entirely different (even a completely opposite) question can be a duplicate if **one** of the many dozens of answers *is* actually an answer to what you ask - *that* isn't always received as particularly helpful.

Comment: Perhaps provide (edit your question, not here in comments) some counterexamples where two completely different questions have the same answer (e.g. two different contexts where the context for the answer is given by the question).