# Show time as DD MMM YY rather than MMM DD YY?

Tags: feature-request, dates

Currently dates are shown as `MMM DD YY` for eg. `jun 11 12`. This is confusing, because it is not widely used.

Rather it would be better if dates are shown as `DD MMM YY` like `11 jun 12`, which is used in large number of countries.

It's a small feature-request. Vote up or down as per your choice. Thanks.

**EDIT:** Cyan is the region where DD/MM is used , Magenta is the region where MM/DD is used.Image taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country).

[image]

Comment: I'd go for ISO8601 formatting (YYYY-MM-DD) instead, otherwise you'd never stop with the localized date formats..

Comment: @MartijnPieters I knew someone would come up with that, but not so quickly.That isn't bad either, just that it's not so famous

Comment: It's clear enough as it is. If it was only numbers, then this feature request would make more sense.

Comment: @AdityaPatil Famous or not, *it's an ISO standard* so you know it's the way to go.

Comment: Ok, should we go ISO way? I'm ready to change question.

Comment: Do you have tangible evidence that `DD MM YY` is more widely used than `MM DD YY` (worldwide)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi `man strftime` says  **%m/%d/%y. Yecch—for Americans  only.Americans should  note  that in other countries %d/%m/%y is rather common. This means that in international context this format is  ambiguous and should not be used.) (SU)**

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Mostly Only US uses MM/DD.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country there's a map! I like maps.

Comment: Got it, thanks :) I did not imagine the US were so isolated in doing that. Clearly that magenta should go :)

Comment: If you change your question to ask for ISO format, it will be a duplicate of [Can we have a user preference for ISO standard date format for all dates/times?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218561/can-we-have-a-user-preference-for-iso-standard-date-format-for-all-dates-times)

Comment: Well, I honestly don't think this will give a big advantage for users. In fact, it may make regular users be confused with sudden change because they have already accustomed to current format. I'm abstaining with a tend to disagree.

Comment: @AndrewT. Changes need to be made someday.

Comment: Note that the `strftime` manpage talks about a **different format** using *only* numbers; `06/11/12` is ambiguous, `jun 11 2012` is not.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks but you may now forget strftime  as we have better proof. The Map!

Comment: @AdityaPatil: What I mean is that *this isn't really as much of an issue* because the month name is in there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The problem is with year and date, when both are under 12.

Comment: The point where it gets really ambiguous is when [the year isn't shown for dates this year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226428/show-the-whole-date-even-for-posts-from-the-current-year)

Comment: may be relevant? [Why does the United States keep using “old” date representations and imperial system, while being in the minority?](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/12089/3266)

Comment: Another advantage to the ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD) is that is sorts correctly, even when it's alpha text.

Comment: What Richard Tingle said. Mar 13 is incredibly ambiguous compared to 13 Mar when the year is omitted.

Answer (score 6):

## Suggestion

I would say; why choose. Now in 2020 internationalisation is old hat. So just show whatever date format the users browser says they want.

## Implementation

My understanding is that Stack Exchange sites are build in [C# ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/09/21/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/). ASP.net is very able to pull the users preferred language out of the data sent from the browser and C# is very able to format a date time in that cultures preferred data format.

## Justification

The current date format regularly causes confusion, as seen in these posts:

[Show the whole date, even for posts from the current year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226428/show-the-whole-date-even-for-posts-from-the-current-year?noredirect=1#comment1191259_226428)

[Why inaccurate ''member for" info is shown in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251091/why-inaccurate-member-for-info-is-shown-in-stack-overflow#226426)

[Don't use very old posts for audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198877/dont-use-very-old-posts-for-audits)

[Allow users to set custom date formats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82156/allow-users-to-set-custom-date-formats?rq=1)

This would mean American users can continue to use their preferred date format of MMM DD 'YY and non American users would feel a little less unloved.

(The current behaviour of showing a UTC timestamp on hover is good, I'd suggest keeping that)

Comment: Related: **1** [Customize displayed timestamp format for Q'n'As](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349883/customize-displayed-timestamp-format-for-qnas) **2** [The date display for the current year is ambiguous. Please fix it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356327/the-date-display-for-the-current-year-is-ambiguous-please-fix-it) **3** [How come the year doesn't show here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221655/) **4** [Add Year to Dates for Dates within 11 Months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15576/)

Comment: Why format dates on the server at all? Send it as ISO date, format it in the preferred display format in the client.

Comment: @polygnome that would indeed be an option. But stackexchange sites feel server side templated rather than something client side templated like react or angular where what you suggest would be the obvious solution

Comment: Then send just ISO format! it WORKS for everyone. If too long, use just the YYYY-MM-DD, that is what matter. People don't care if the minutes and seconds when people wrote, it is useless info.If user ever wants time, can do mouse over. But at least the date can be read by everyone without guessing

Comment: @higuita I personally would be very happy with that, but it might be a step too far for our american friends