# Customize displayed timestamp format for Q&As

Tags: feature-request, dates

After a while Q&A's timestamps are displayed in a long format like `Jun 24'20 1:23`. I request to display the mentioned format by default but to introduce a profile option to customize the timestamp by a preferred format.

The reason for this request:

I'm a native German. Our timestamp format (according to the mentioned example) is `24. Juni 2020, 1:23`. The short version will be `24.06.2020, 1:23`. The date is in the ascending priority of time units.

As a software engineer I'm very used to a standardized international format like `2020-06-24 01:23`. That format displays the date in the descending priority order of time units.

I'm using StackOverflow that often during the day. But I'm not getting used to that standard format. Programming languages have changed so fast that timestamps are very important to filter out outdated answers. And very often I get confused with the standard format, which isn't displaying the date in a sorted manner.

To clarify: This is a request for the long timestamp of Q&As a while ago only and not for currently posted ones whose timestamp is displayed differently and is clearly recognizable as an actual Q&A.

Comment: I would like this actually. Being English I find these time stamps a bit confusing sometimes at a glance. It would be nice to have the option but I don't think they will change it though, this a standard way to do it online.

Comment: You can actually hover over the time stamps to get the international format. You can also sort answers with oldest first. These aren't solutions but they may at least help.

Comment: @MarkKirby I agree this is the standard way. But StackOverflow in particular is one of the most frequented platforms of SE. This would be a reasonable feature in a daily job-workflow of a lot of software engineers. Today I searched for "php interface static methods". Not to be too technichal: this wasn't possible til PHP 5.3. So answeres like "it's not possible" are outdated since 2011. A date like `Jun 13'11` is confusing in the first place. It could mean (german view) `2013-06-11` but really meant `2011-06-13`. The standard way doesn't contribute to the globalized iNet world.

Comment: @Catija As I mentioned in my previous comment it's about job-workflows. I agree it's a workaround in the first place, but I'd recommend to have it visible immediately while I load the thread.