# Could Stack Exchange be less American-centric?

Tags: discussion, company, the-loop

In the loop survey, a question wrecks my mind:

> [image: Which racial background(s) do you identify with? Please select all that apply. (optional)]

*Note that this survey has been updated; the [original version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ4Pb.png) had far fewer options which [staff explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339050/the-loop-has-arrived-what-does-the-community-think-about-it?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1130860_339057) was a mistake.*

Of course I selected **Other: Human** as an answer. Yes I identify as such.

This question feels so USA-centric. The USA has a huge problem with race. I don't deny it and we are not here to fix it. I know that as an American company SE has to follow the US law, but as far as I know they don't have to follow this kind of trend. The USA is not the only country with this racist behavior, but here it really feels like a case of [Americentrism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americentrism):

> Americentrism is the tendency among some Americans to assume the culture of the United States is more important than those of other countries or to judge foreign cultures based on the standards within their own. It refers to the practice of viewing the world from an overly US-focused perspective, with an implied belief, either consciously or subconsciously, in the preeminence of American culture

In fact, in my own country, racist questions like this are one of the biggest taboos. You. Just. Don't. It feels so wrong in so many aspects.

[image: We don't do that here.]

I know we can't please every culture. I just hope that SE Inc will keep in mind that their community come from all around the world.

Quite related to: [Allow users to set custom date formats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82156/allow-users-to-set-custom-date-formats)

Comment: I wondered if I should answer White or Hispanic being a white european / hispanic / spaniard. I joked a bit myself alone when they asked me that question. My mother family comes from France and my father has probably arabian gens, but I look white or pinky on a glass so I answeed White European because I am europeist :)

Comment: @Universal_learner Exactly. What about someone from Martinique? Are they less European than someone from Bavaria? This is f*cked up.

Comment: @Universal_learner, I know that the question has since been edited to include the option now, but the screenshot shown was also from the time that if you were of African descent, there wasn't even an option for you. Race seems to be a pivotal thing for Americans, and focusing on perceived races (whether with good or bad intentions) usually ends up dividing communities by group characteristics, and I'm not a fan of that

Comment: @KyleFairns I think that's the most offensive thing here, that African isn't even an option. Like Africans don't exist, while they come from a bloody huge continent and have been much discriminated against already. This is a screw-up of major proportions.

Comment: @Mast It is an option now. You may have seen a screenshot depicting it's not, but it was added later and claimed to be a "mistake".

Comment: So something you don't understand and dismiss out of hand is "American" and something you know about and accept is from your country - you know what everyone calls that? --- The *good* [reason to ask about race](https://www.census.gov/acs/www/about/why-we-ask-each-question/race/) (and gender) is to ensure that no group is ignored or disadvantaged. --- You can see from my answers that I help people equally, and might infer from the user names that the persons helped are from various genders and their heritage (or current location) is not the USA. Did you want to make the question more polite?

Comment: @Rob I have never been asked such a question outside the Americas (and for good reasons). And I've visited plenty of countries. The question is very much American, though not restricted to the US.

Comment: I hope the evaluation of the survey results isn't just non-white + bad experience == racial issues on SE/SO or non-male + bad experience == gender issues on SE/SO.

Comment: People from outside North America ask such questions: "[Is it rude to ask tourists where they are from?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/1539/7238)", or "[How to make clear to people I don't want to answer their “Where are you from?” question?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/22103/7238)".  See also: "[Is it rude to ask someone where they are from originally?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/3457/7238)".

Comment: @Rob "Where are you from?" and "What race are you?" are *very* different questions. In the last question you link, asking "Where are you from *originally?"* suggests asking about race as well. And guess what; the question is asked by someone from the US.

Comment: Talking about ethnicity can be relevant in a specific IPS or travel thread. Flagging people by race in a wide SE survey is utterly racist and should be call as such.

Comment: I totally concur. Seeing this kind of question makes me cringe. It's intention can only be to put people in boxes; it gives means to further discrimination. It's even less relevant than what religion a person has or what sexual identity they possess etc. It can only be used to discriminate... and often there's no clear answer. And even then: the answers are totally irrelevant to what is discussed in a knowledge-exchange site. One should ask what people care about. Not what they look like.

Comment: @planetmaker the good old adage: _On the Internet, nobody knows you're a dog_

Comment: @aloisdgsaysReinstateMonica yes. And it doesn't matter, whether dog or priest or farmer. I'm quite happy do without these racist questions over here in Europe; I only see these kind of race/racist questions asked from American companies, thus being exposed to them very rarely

Comment: @planetmaker this is the whole problem. SE is an American company with a international audience. They should behave as such.

Comment: There's even UK government guidance on how to ask this question in the UK; and certain (public) sectors are mandated to ensure that they're not discriminating, in which case asking the question might be their best way of doing so. So it isn't purely an American thing. https://www.ethnicity-facts-figures.service.gov.uk/ethnic-groups and https://www.ons.gov.uk/methodology/classificationsandstandards/measuringequality/ethnicgroupnationalidentityandreligion

Comment: If my forefathers were kicked out of Spain in 1492, does that make me "Hispanic Descent"? Also "European Descent" for another part of my family running away from the Khmelnitsky pogroms in the 1650s, most definitely "Middle-eastern" for getting exiled in 70CE. No, wait, the Nazis who were so very keen on "race" were also quite explicit on us being a separate race, no matter where we came from. I guess I'm "other".

Comment: @GalastelsupportsGoFundMonica I think you qualify as Human. At least, can I treat you as such?

Comment: Definitely Human. :)

Comment: The [company doing the survey](https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/take-a-tour-2/?ut_source=mp&ut_source2=take-a-tour-2&ut_source3=megamenu&utm_expid=.tSzOnORwTpSzOdV38DlebA.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.surveymonkey.com%2Fmp%2Ftake-a-tour-2%2F%3Fut_source%3Dsurvey_poweredby_howitworks) ensures [anonymity](https://www.surveymonkey.com/curiosity/sensitive-topics-methodology/?ut_source=mp&ut_source2=survey-guidelines&ut_source3=inline&ut_ctatext=Sensitive%2520Survey%2520Questions%253A%2520What%2520To%2520Do%252C%2520What%2520Not%2520To%2520Do). If SE "*discriminated*" they could IP block.

Comment: This ^ is [your *better* fight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339133/how-should-the-new-pronoun-policy-be-applied-to-spanish-language#comment1131181_339133), gender is important to many people too.

Comment: @Rob This is a bit out of topic... In France, I think there is better way to fight sexism than to fight the french grammar with inclusive writing. French, as a language, is quite gender heavy. Keep in mind that inclusive writing is not neutral (or genderless) writing. It is about using the two french gender everywhere. In English, the terms `a user` is quite neutral. In french, an inclusive writer would write `un·e utilisateur·trice`. I can get behind the idea, but I prefer to avoid it personally in favor of a genderless french. Sexism is a large problem. There are different ways to fight it.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl Notice the difference in the UK "ethnicity" questions - they include cultural origin and don't pretend that everyone with the same skin colour is the same.

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8 but they still want to know skin colour

Comment: aloisdgsaysReinstateMonica - Thanks for explaining the difference, the problem is that the world has a history of *seeing* approximately half the population as (for want of a better paraphrase, but at least this isn't wordy) *a lessor contributor* to the future (avoiding the word "Mankind"). It's excellent that there's been significant improvement in the past few decades, but I don't think we should *rest* until no one is left behind.

Comment: When Stack Overflow did [The Developer Survey](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/04/09/the-2019-stack-overflow-developer-survey-results-are-in/) they simply reported the results, they didn't say: "People use Python because they don't know other languages, or dislike Assembly coding". We should assume that in this case that they will simply report the results, and not say something against any particular group.

Comment: @Rob _I don't think we should rest until no one is left behind._ I fully agree with this part. I dont know the english marxist word for this, but it french we call this _La convergence des luttes_. We must fight all those archaic inequality as one. We are a plural and diverse force. Unity is strength.

Comment: @Rob assuming good faith is the way to go, but I want them to know that this question is wrong in other culture. We, as a community, are not constrain by America's racist culture.

Comment: aloisdgsaysReinstateMonica - That is where we come full circle: `We, as a community, are not constrain by America's racist culture.` - [Most *Americans* aren't native American](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_and_ethnicity_in_the_United_States#Ancestry) but instead are immigrants. Essentially you argue that people leave their own country, come to America, and become racist; a big bunch of self-haters. I disagree. If it's so awful why come here, to be both a part of the problem and protest it ...

Comment: @Rob This is a bit of a strawman. I am not saying that people leaving there are racists. A racist culture developed and rose there. This is a place where it is normal to identify people by race. I dont think that people at SE Inc are racists. I want to highlight that this question, as is, is racist. If it is fine in America, it is not in other part of the world.

Comment: *living not leaving in my last comment

Comment: This isn't how all of America thinks, either.  This sort of hyper-attention to race is a _subset_ of American culture.  It just seems like it's everybody, because that subset is making all the noise.

Comment: @Benjol: Best comment of the year :-)

Comment: @aloisdg "If it is fine in America, it is not in other parts of the world". But if it is important to know in America, but not in other parts of the world, should it be included?

Comment: @MattGutting _accepted_  is a better term than _fine_ I would say

Comment: @aloisdg understood - but I don't think that answers the question.

Comment: @MattGutting I dont know. Maybe they could localize it to the US or just avoid altogether.

Comment: aloisdgsaysReinstateMonica - `I am not saying that people living there ...` - That statement is [unsupported by fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terms_for_ethnic_exogroups) or what you wrote. Much [longer list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ethnic_slurs), most of which are not of US origin.

Comment: I checked all the boxes including other, and filled in Gnome. The question is silly and always bothered me when I lived in the US

Comment: @Rob What point are you trying to make? That there are racist slurs outside the US? There are racist slurs everywhere, obviously. The point is that in the US, as opposed to most of the rest of the world, it is *normal* and *acceptable* to identify people by race, and to ask about someone's race in a survey. Such institutionalized racism is reminiscent of the Nazi and Fascist regimes of the 30s and 40s in some parts. It is therefore quite offensive to many people to talk about race in such a way.

Comment: @Inactive-ObjectingExtremism In the US it is done to measure that no group is unfairly treated. In other parts of the world it's not what one would normally call a "survey"; being stopped by the government and either detained, *re-educated* or interred. It's ***because*** the US history is different and they are a continent that gets along with its neighbors that questions can be asked (that ***you*** have the right to be wrong, and to say so), whereas elsewhere there are concerns about the "Committee of protection", "Central Committee", "Secret State Police" (all such nice sounding names).

Comment: I checked other, and filled: "None of your damn business"

Comment: @aloisdg says Reinstate Monica If they are going to do Big Data with it, I will trust more a study about French programmers, Spanish programmers.... That can reflect something, how is France good on teaching code to the childs. Excuse if I am not fair with african people, but to leave in the same group someone who has studied in a french university and someone who has studied in Africa because they have the same skill color just leads to inconsistent data and a study I won't trust on.

Comment: ... if I chose Hispanic is the same, South America universities are not so bad than africans, but my data is gonna travel to a group I don't belong to and this can leads to an uncorrect perception that Spain universities are worse than they are.

Comment: @Universal_learner I am also a Spaniard and I am always puzzled by that kind of question. Because let's face it: most Americans a.w.a. Europeans north of the Pyrenees think Spaniards are not White, while most Latinos a.w.a. Spaniards themselves think Spaniards are not Latino, so... In the end I checked ***Other: Mediterranean*** ^_^

Comment: Hah! Yes. I did the survey yesterday and **that was exactly** my response: _This is a US-centric question._

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what’s wrong with this exactly? Sorry, I acknowledge I’m definitely pretty ignorant as a white American about race in other countries. **What is the "racist question" and American centric thing—just the fact that there is any question at all about race?**

Comment: Note: If you selected *Biracial*, please indicate which races so that SE can rank how marginalized you are. (Apparently selecting *Multiracial* is used to indicate three or more ethnicities.The distinction between two and three-plus is evidently very important to SE.)

Comment: Grrrrrrrrrr..WOOF!

Comment: @MartinJames On the Internet, now we knows you're a dog

Comment: @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com I might be a bitch for all you know, and am I golden, chocolate or black?  :)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381016/update-wording-in-100k-email-subject

Answer (score 141, accepted):

### It's not that they're America-centered - they're *self*-centered.

Part of the SE Inc. staff seem to have enclosed themselves in a bubble, possibly with some peers and friends on social media. In that bubble, there are different laws of nature, of society and of logic...

- They decide what people care about;
- They decide which public phenomena occur and which do not;
- They decide what problems people on SE are facing;
- Only what they believe should be done about it, can be done at all.

So it stands to reason that their preconceptions define what race is and what the recognized races are. (And that a race question should be on a survey. And that this survey and the "loop" mechanism is what's missing right now, which is [really not the case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339053/196834)).

Comment: Well, it's actually kind of American-centric. I recall that some 20 years ago  I was in the US and went with a friend who had to take the SSN. The form he had to fill asked the race. We were like: What?! Are they kidding? At the end he had to ask the office clerk what race he had to write, because we had no idea.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: It's only American-centric because they're from the US and it's fashionable to make everything about race in pseudo-progressive US politics right now. BTW - In Germany and the Netherlands, you need to supply your date-of-birth on all sorts of completely irrelevant forms.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica A detail: date-of-birth (and place of birth) are important for the *identity* (and not that of "identity politics", but the *technical process* of *identifying* a person). Saying "I'm Hans Müller" is not enough. "I'm Hans Müller, born 1970-10-20 in Berlin" narrows this down sufficiently. Beyond that, I think that this whole concept of "race" doesn't make much sense in the end, but the fact that it does not make *sense* does not mean that the concept does not *exist* (and its existence causes all sorts of troubles...)

Comment: @Marco13: 1. They shouldn't need to ID you that much (if at all). 2. email is sufficient to distinguish between people, and if you want to be old-school than plain mailing address.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica: Your birthday determines whether you're 13+, 16+ or 18+, which directly affects how Europeans business may interact with you. The GDRP contains an explicit "Data is needed to satisfy a legal obligation" rule. Race on the other hand is pretty much the opposite. Since there's no legal need for that data, you need a very pressing concern to even ask about it.

Comment: @MSalters-reinstateMonica: When your age is relevant, you're right. But why does, day, a hotel need to know my birth date - after I've already booked and paid and am now checking in?

Comment: I would love an official answer from one of the staff behind this survey. I will accept this answer for now, because it is the most credible answer.

Comment: @aloisdgsaysReinstateMonica: My answer is also an explanation of why you are unlikely to get such an answer.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica indeed.

Comment: Someone needs to tell the USA that prior to the 16th century no concept like that which we know today as "race" existed and from the 16th to the 21st centuries the concept has gone through quite a few re-edits. It is early-Modern pseudo-scientific babble, convenient for those who wanted to justify the Transatlantic Slave Trade and the Southern Plantations. Any "White" American might benefit from understanding that they are not "White" at all, never have been and trying to divide the world's population into "White" and "not-White" does literally no-one any favours.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica: wrt. why German hotels ask for your date of birth: because they are required by law (https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bmg/__30.html) (which doesn't answer the obvious follow-up question why the law thinks they should ask this)

Comment: @cbeleitessupportsMonica: It's funny how Germany is at the same time concerned about data privacy and concerned about you providing them with a bunch of private data. It's also a nightmare to register a SIM card.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica: nah, you got it all wrong. After all, the state *is*  more equal, isn't it? </sarcasm> More seriously: as long as we can take this as *funnny*, things are comparatively well. And on yet another note, we still have  funny and inconsistent bits and pieces of obedience to authorities left where everyone looking from the outside and saying it's obvious and we should know better considering our authoritarian experiences would be totally right IMHO (thinking along the lines of paying cash for a SIM card and then registering that, same for the hotel).

Answer (score 114):

This sort of thing is annoying *even to Americans*. I am part of an "invisible" ethnic group here in the USA. Anthropologists and sociologists generally admit that we exist, and sometimes even describe qualitative ways that they understand us to be different than others, but hard *quantitative* data is sorely lacking. If I want to see how my "people" are doing in terms of gaining higher education, avoiding incarceration, improving life expectancy, not eating the purple berries, etc., the data simply isn't there - we are lumped in with other people who are quite different from us, have different cultural practices, tend to talk differently, etc.

For a while, I've wanted to solve this by simply adding survey options so that "my" people become one of the options. That isn't really a solution, because where does it end? There are hundreds of ethnic, cultural, religious, social, sociopolitical, etc. groups here and elsewhere that are advantaged and/or disadvantaged in some way, and there are always divisions *within* a group that may trigger a desire to add even more options. I know someone who is descended from Québécois who moved to New England in the early 20th century and who considers himself distinct from the Acadiens of Maine and the Cajun of Louisiana in a "not my people" sense. How many "French-American" groups do we need on the form?

The problem does not end there. People who have emigrated from Africa to the USA have told me that they do not feel "African-American" or even understand African-American culture, cuisine, linguistics, etc. Does that mean we need to split the form to contain "African-American" and "African-African" options? "Africa" isn't homogeneous - does someone from Ethiopia living in one of Washington DC's ethnic Ethiopian neighborhoods feel the same way about where the widget industry is going as a Congolese engineering student attending Texas A&M? If *so*, what does that even *mean*? What would you do with such data? What about that Moroccan chef in Miami? Is he even "African" at all, or is he Arab? What is Arab anyway? If he claims to be neither African nor Arab, but a member of the "Happy Fun Rainbow People", do we accept that at face value or do we require him to provide evidence of cultural rituals, a documented history, etc.?

The reality is that the sort of data gathered by the form above has little meaning. Why was it even selected? What do you hope to gain from it? If the answer is "We don't know" or "Everyone else was using this survey question, so we did too", then you have your answer right there - there's no point to it. If you gather garbage data then your results will naturally be garbage.

Comment: You raise an important point here. With bad question, you get useless answers and make awful decision. Data-driven ... the wrong way. By the way, sorry that this overly racist culture of classifying people like this exist where you live.

Comment: Take it as a sign from the gods you should not be filling out that survey :-P

Comment: What does "not eating the purple berries" refer to? My search skills aren't good enough to find out on my own.

Comment: @DanielFischer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=je8MZPSAEws

Comment: I see. I even know the Simpsons. Thanks.

Comment: I've often wondered: how far could a "white" US citizen born in South Africa get with calling himself (legitimately based on **the actual words**) "African American" for "affirmative action" purposes - e.g., scholarships, preferred admission to schools, jobs, etc. Which would be stupid, but could easily happen because this country has a thing against actually saying "black" (which really isn't correct either, because "black" skin color isn't exclusively from Africa, and isn't actually "black" but just a rather dark shade of brown, but which is clearly what is *meant* by "African American").

Comment: @manassehkatz-ReinstateMonica Probably quite far if he (they? Hope nobody sees...) wanted to; an ex-colleague of mine was able to take advantage of an affirmative action program because he was born in Botswana, when his parents were on (Christian) mission there for two years. He has no relation to the African continent other than having lived there for the first few months of his life (in a compound).

Comment: Yeah, somehow the EU has 28 different nations with at least 28 different racial sub-groups, but they're all clumped together as "white"...

Comment: @JonathanReezSupportsMonica Well... The experience of that differs, if you happen to be, say, a former yugoslav living in, say, Sweden. The differentness is certainly there, but at least it is not government imposed. It is interesting that in Europe, religion has been the historically important factor for hostility. Catholics, protestants, heretics, pagans, jews, muslim.

Comment: That's _precisely_ where "White" and "Black" comes from though, isn't it? Right up to 16th century it's easy to distinguish between the _righteous, superior Christians from Christendom (ie. Europe)_ and the _faithless, inferior pagans_. But then things get messy because trade expands early Modern Missionaries are doing well spreading the good word. Suddenly _Christian_ and _Heathen_ aren't such good indicators of superiority and inferiority any more. So two new concepts emerge to replace them. Yes, it's "White" and "Black"! Now you can be a Christian from Africa and **still** be inferior.

Comment: @Robert Columbia: The je8MZPSAEws video is not available. What was its title, etc.?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum It was the "I eated the purple berries" skit. lKJwXhZ-UL0 is an adequate replacement.

Answer (score 81):

I am an Australian of British descent, and I would not answer a question that required me to identify as White.  I used Other rather than tick the first checkbox.

I see many US Census records and have never understood why the colour of a person's skin should be asked.

Comment: In countries where race is a political hot point they use these types of questions to ensure affirmative action and the like is enforced.

Comment: @Beyers In Australia it is an option to identify with an ethnicity. Skin color is not used to name them.

Comment: @PolyGeo Ethnicity and race are two vastly different concepts. It seems the Australian census bureau understands this, but the makers of the loop survey do not.

Comment: @PolyGeo regarding the state-issues census I think I can think of at least one reason why ethnic profiling could be relevant: it can help the state to decide which infrastructure is the most helpful for its citizens. Sadly there is a correlation between wealth, ethnicity, safety, etc. in ethnically homogeneous neighborhoods. Also maybe to get accurate statistics on voting figures and eligibility, and thus help prevent discrimination at voting time (which is definitely a thing in the US). But that's just speculation really.

Comment: Please don't take that survey.

Comment: Or take the survey but ensure the answers you give can not help them bias this towards race, gender or age ...

Comment: Race and ethnicity are actually separate categories in the US (at least in the healthcare space). But you only get 3 options for ethnicity: "Hispanic/Latino", "Not Hispanic/Latino", or "Refused to answer." I know that for race, there are multiple tiers that the CDC (and I think FQHC's) have been trying mandate that orgs collect that seem less racist (eg they actually go into specific tribal memberships for first nation/inuit, and you can select more than one option). They still roll up to an upper tier (eg, English->European->white). https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/dvs/Race_Ethnicity_CodeSet.pdf

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard Slavery was a part of many countries' histories, right?

Comment: I used other and wrote "I object to this question".

Answer (score 65):

I fail to see **any** reason why profiling questions are included.

The purpose (we were told) of "the loop" is to tell SE what we think.  The ethnic or economic status or sex of people telling them this *should not matter*.

The obvious question then is will SE Inc ignore or give different weight to opinions of different ethic, economic, social or geopolitical groups?

I'd have to assume "yes" would be the answer or there would be no purpose in them asking at all.

What has this ...

> We’re going to be sharing our product development process with you, from feedback loops to timelines.  We’ll be doing so through our new series – The Loop. You can give us your thoughts on what you’d like to see us do by filling out this survey: Through the Loop

... got to do with gathering profiling information on who answers?

This seems quite at odds with all the high words we hear from SE Inc about openness and anti-discrimination.

Is this another in the series of "accidents" SE Inc management seem so prone to having, or is it simply more evidence of hypocrisy?

The very last thing that should be happening is a process that lets managements at SE gather information that could bias the inclusiveness of opinions expressed.

This is the opposite of open and transparent.

Comment: SE has stated, time and again, that they want (need to) make SO more welcoming for people of marginalized communities specifically. How do you propose they measure that otherwise?

Comment: @mag This means SE will decide who is marginalized (and to which extent) based on a magical algorithm that takes into account your answers on gender, race and age. Don't know about that as a measure of measuring things.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica You can see me as far or extremist left and I agree with the idea of being welcoming to anybody doing at least some basic searching online. The problem here is that SE has a learning curve (not a steep one, but still) and per se not welcoming to beginner. This is not a bug this is a feature. SE can help easing the curve, but they are looking elsewhere (this survey, the CoC, etc.). Sexism, racism, ageism and any other form of discrimination should be banned. I dont want your gender. I dont want to know your age. I just want to help you fixing your problem.

Comment: I can [think of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339183/196834) a reason actually.

Comment: @mag, I'm not sure how much I trust them picking which marginalized communities are in need of additional welcoming when version 1.0 of the survey *left out Black people entirely*

Comment: What a weird obsession, so bizarre

Comment: @mag My viewpoint is that making people of *any* kind welcome is best achieved by specifically **not** drawing a distinction between people based on any categorization.  So my view is that categorization is the problem, not the solution.  Or to rephrase á la Mel Brooks : "Categories ?  We don't need no stinking categories ". :-)  The more you point out that a community needs special treatment, the more you marginalize it and define it as different.  That's my view so measurement is counterproductive from that standpoint.

Comment: @StephenG Categorization of people that identity ask question askers, answer providers, editors, queue monitors would actually be a much more meaningful way of gathering data for the welcome wagon.

Comment: I'm not making an argument either way but merely explaining why I think they do what they do.

Comment: SE clearly has a hypothesis that folks from underrepresented groups have a worse experience / are less likely to use SO. There's also similar research and stats and stories regarding the tech industry as a whole. So now what? Either they can 1) collect data to determine whether or not there's a correlation and can make better informed decisions, or, 2) simply discard this hypothesis based on your belief that it "shouldn't" matter.

Comment: @EmC How effective can data analysis be done on a survey that does not ask the participant whether their experiences on the site are related to their race/gender/age? There is no way of _correlating_ let alone finding _causality_ with such surveys.

Comment: Given a data set that includes self-identified labels and ratings, you absolutely can calculate a correlation and error bars between those labels and ratings. If you want more details, perhaps try one of the relevant stacks (stats or datascience)?

Comment: @Magisch Wouldn't not knowing the race of the user at all make it even easier to not discriminate? The only way you could "not discriminate" is by giving all races/sexes the same say.

Comment: How many of us truly know for sure our descent?  I was asked by an oncologist if I was of  ashkenazi jewish descent -- her concern was did I carry the BRACA genes.  I started to say that I was of Swedish and Scottish descent, and then thought "How do I know what a greatgrandmother did with a guest one cold northern night?"   So that's what I said.   And I answered  the SE question by saying I was part Neanderthal, which is a subspecies of Homo sapiens.

Comment: @ab2ReinstateMonicaNow should have done the same given i have the blue eyes mutation and my cousins/uncles the redhead, so i'm probably carrying it too. Will keep it in mind for next genetically-powered survey.

Comment: Questions that ask about race or sex, will only result in answers that generate data, that will be false.  I will purposefully select every negative/positive/neutral option on every survey I take.  **If these questions are not on the survey then truthful data will be provided.**  My race and sex has nothing to do with asking a question and/or answering questions on this network.

Answer (score 56):

Let me talk for a minute about the problem of being "other". It seems like such a neutral word, doesn't it? "I happen to not fit into those above categories, no harm done". When you're the "other" once, it's no harm done. But listen to me as someone who for 2000 years has been the "other", and suffered for being the "other".

When monotheism was still this newfangled thing, we were the "other". The Greeks came in with their surveys of what we call our sun-god and war-god and so on, like they did in any place they conquered, and we marked "other" on their papers, and had idols installed in our Temple, and were executed for refusing to bow to it.

When Christianity and Islam came by, we were the "other". Come the crusaders, the Inquisition, the Farhud, forced conversions, 1492 - exiled from Spain, 1650s - massacred in Ukraine. On the map of the Old World, there isn't a single place where we haven't been exiled from at least once.

Come Enlightenment, and scientific theories, religion is no longer important. Now we talk of race. And again we are the "other". It doesn't matter if for the past few centuries we lived in Europe or Asia or Africa. It doesn't matter if our skin is pale or brown or dark. It doesn't matter what god we worship, or if we worship any god at all. A drop of our blood is a contaminant unto the third generation. We are a race of our own, the "other" race. I'm not even sure what "race" is, seems like utter pseudo-science to me, but sure enough this pseudo-science was twisted to make us a special and distinct "other".

We are *always* the "other", the one that isn't recognised, the one that has no right to be. Make no mistake - "other" means "we don't know what you are", and from there it's one easy step to "we don't recognise you", "we do not accept you". In surveys, "other" usually equals "the ones we don't care about, so we threw them into one big box".

There are other "other"s among us - other groups who struggle for recognition, for rights, for whatever. **The way we welcome others is we don't try to fit them into neat little boxes devised by someone who thinks he knows better.** If for some reason SE wants to know about our nationality or ethnicity, or some other demographic, they can make it an open question. Don't tell us where we "should" belong - let us tell you where we *do* belong.

And for the love of everything you hold dear, don't use the word "race". That thing is abhorrent to the [core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_racism).

Comment: I chose "Middle East".

Comment: Wow, you're 2,000 years old? :-P ... More seriously though, religious identity is not "racial" identity. That is, Nazi policy to the contrary, you don't switch "races" if you convert to Judaism, nor are Jews of a single "race" (in the sense that, say, there are light-skinned Slav Jews and dark-skinned African Jews and so on).

Comment: And similar things happen within this group. In Israel today, Sephardim and Mizrachim are sometimes considered "others", "ethnics", or "technically with us but not *really* like us". Beta Israel is sometimes considered *completely* "other".

Comment: It's even worse than you describe.  My wife and I never had children, so our single friends couldn't relate to us anymore, and the married with children couples don't relate to us either.  My pastor once told a story of how he walked down a street in Jerusalem, and watched two Hasidic Jews pass each other in the street without so much as an acknowledgement to each other.  When he asked about that, he was told "oh, one of them had a different number of hair curls, right?  They're from two different Jewish sects that hate each other."

Comment: @RobertHarvey You realize that 1) non-acknowledgement while walking down the street is not necessarily a symptom of "hate", and 2) "hate" is a little strong when describing strong disagreement (_everybody on Meta "hates", right? _) . I would suggest also that you're hearing the explanation filtered through a number of layers, each of which might add it's own "other"-style sediment; either party directly involved might have provided different perspectives. (NB _a different number of hair curls_ -- to my knowledge it's only ever two or none; nobody sports three or five for example.)

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica Jews are a classic example of an ethno-religious group. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnoreligious_group Other such groups include the Druze and the Yazidis. Consider: we think of ourselves as "a people", right? All our religious stories are about what happened to our forefathers - an ethnic element. And when someone converts to Judaism, one becomes one of the people - he joins not only in the religious worship, but in the heritage. I don't know if that constitutes "race", I'm not clear on what "race is", but we're certainly as much ethnic group as religious.

Comment: @ColumbiasaysReinstateMonica Yeh, we should really try to be better at this whole "one people" thing.

Comment: "We think of ourselves as a people, right?" <- No. We don't, and we aren't. That conflation of religion and nationality is a recent development due to Zionism. Also, most of the history of our forefathers is actually culturally erased by the Israeli education system. I was taught nothing about the Jewish communities in my grandparents' countries of origin.

Comment: @ZevSpitz: It's not my story.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica I was taught about Spain before 1492 and the Anusim after, about Poland and about Lithuania, about the Ukraine, a little but not nearly enough about the Maghreb, about Iraq - only the Farhud, about Israel in the 14th-17th centuries and 19th century onwards, about Ethiopia - only the basics about the forced conversion and the horrid journey to Israel. Quite lacking, but I just felt it was overall bad, lacking all around.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica As for conflating religion and ethnicity, it appears for example in the Kuzari. Judah HaLevi explains how we are all direct descendants of the folk who walked out of Egypt and stood at Mount Sinai.

Comment: @GalastelsupportsGoFundMonica: Yeah, well, we absolutely aren't. The  main "sources" of Jewish communities are the Khazarian kingdom, North-African converts, the kingdom of Khimyar, and "miscellaneous immigrants and converts". Also, an Egypt exodus never happened.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica Archaeological finds suggest that the Egypt exodus did happen, but rather than being this one massive event, it was a migration of disparate groups across several decades. Hence the Tribes. But that's beside the point. The Exodus is a founding myth, same as Rome's founding myth included Aeneas fleeing from Troy. An ethnic group shares a culture (among other things) - shares stories. The Exodus has been a story that we carried as a focal point in our tradition for a very long time.

Comment: @GalastelsupportsGoFundMonica: I disagree, but we're getting way off topic...

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica As for converts vs. direct descendants, there is a lot of research being done on this, including genetic research. Most certainly we cannot deny chains of literature and scholarship - texts, that go in direct lines from Israel to Babylon, Greece, Rome, Byzantium, then the Rhine valley, France and Spain. Those texts are proof of our presence there, and what we did there.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica Yup, very definitely off topic. :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Never said it was, and I apologize if I came across a little strong. (Although technically, you did retweet it  ). But the interpretation of "two strangers passing by without acknowledging each other" as "two people who only see the Other" disturbs me, especially when from my perspective it's a very shallow view. OTOH I think the (mis)interpretation itself -- and the ease with which that interpretation is accepted -- is a powerful example of "other"-style treatment -- an innocent encounter becomes a demonstration of hatred because the participants are "other".

Comment: What is the story with the Greeks you're referring to? I assume this is something from the Hellenistic years, but "surveys"? About _your_ "sun-god and war-god"? I assume you mean _their_? But, if so, could you link me to some reference for the Greeks imposing their religion and killing those who refused to follow? Sounds interesting. I've never heard of Hellenistic period Greeks getting hung up on another religion, especially since Alexander adopted various characteristics from local religions.

Comment: @terdon-stopharmingMonica Antiochus IV Epiphanes issued decrees forbidding Jewish religious practice, pillaged the Temple and instituted worship of Greek gods inside it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiochus_IV_Epiphanes As for "surveys", that was a little tongue-in-cheek, but the Greeks, as well as the Romans later, were very quick to incorporate aspects of local gods into their similar gods and vice versa. If you have many gods, adding one more, or adding one more aspect to an existing god, doesn't present too much of a problem. Monotheism proved problematic in this regard.

Comment: @GalastelsupportsGoFundMonica thanks, I'd never heard of that!

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Honestly asking, how is your pastor's story related?

Comment: I select every single options, none of the options, and a custom option.  I refuse to be part of their data collection metric, so I will be part of every metric, and every decision.

Answer (score 32):

This is now the list.

[image]

This is a bit better, but I cannot answer the question neither as I am from Spain; I am both hispanic and european descent.

Hispanic

> The term Hispanic (Spanish: hispano or hispánico) refers to the people that originate from, or reside, in Hispanic America, **or from Spain**.
>   [Hispanic, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hispanic)

Also I know you call southamericans latins, but truely French, Spanish, Italian, Rumanian and Portugues languages are latin, so this list may have sense in US, but not in Europe.

I don't have any trouble of sharing my personal data for statics with the community that helped me on programing learning proccess freely, but if you are going to classify us, classify us well. Big Data only works if data is correct, if not it is a waste of time.

**Edit** I want to add this list is unfair with arabian people. There is not an option for arabians while arabians contributed to development of mathematics, the basis behind code.

Comment: And neither can answer it portuguese, italian or greek people, unless SE intends to reunite "the empire where the sun never sets" or to tell them they're swedish now. Nor turkish, Nor balcanic....

Comment: @CptEric they should try a larger list including scandinavian, southern/latin, saxon, balcanic etc to cover propertly Europe, but many people as me will still be confused.

Comment: @CptEric  Greeks, Italians and Portuguese (and Spanish) all fit under "White or European descent". Silly as it may be, in English, the term "latino" refers to South Americans. Yes, it is horribly ignorant, but that's how it is.  I agree that the entire question is both pointless and offensive, but "European" is one of the options, so that covers all of us down here.

Comment: @terdon-stopharmingMonica The ( highly unnecessary and rude to classify as ) biologically ( which i guess is what this horrible question is about ) speaking distinct rus, norse, celt, turkish, greek, iberian, latin, northern-african, and more i miss to mention ethnicities living in europe would like to have a talk about that "us".

Comment: @CptEric huh? This question is pointless, but all I am saying is that if we have a "European" category, then a Greek and a Finn are equally European. Of course they're not the same ethnic or "racial" groups, but they are European. That just doesn't mean anything, but then neither do any of the other groups on offer. And I know how diverse Europeans are. I have Greek, French, English, Scottish, US and Danish direct ancestors in the 4 generations above me.

Comment: yup but racial is on the question. they just need to review how they use language. Is this for a racial study? I am for [open discussion](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/24919/why-are-there-few-or-no-black-super-gms), but the case of France is extremely relevant. There are a lot of blacks that have studied in a good university. that's more important than your colour skill.

Comment: so a study I won't trust on. My data as hispanic is gonna be grouped with the mexicans (Mexico University is not bad, we have more luck than french blacks), the french black community included in groups of people that have studied in Africa

Comment: And the White European group is goona be a mix of USA+EU universities level

Comment: Exactly my point, if they are really that into knowing people's Race, which for me is culturally rude and irresponsible for a company to ask,  European makes as sense as labeling us as Milkywayans. It adds no value, mixes origins, and basically treats the network as if we were crayons, ready to be color-labeled.

Comment: @CptEric oh indeed. Absolutely agreed. None of these categories make any sense to me. I was just saying that "European", while completely uninformative, is broad enough to include both "Spanish" and "Greek". I have _no_ idea why they would ask this question in the first place, however.

Comment: The question makes people "pick a side".  That's the way to create discrimination, not the solution to it.

Comment: Incidentally I am quite offended by the "white or of European decent" category.  I've gone to school with and worked with and had as friends people who were not white and were definitely European.  It's really, really racists to imply a connection between European and white skin color.  Our national football team doesn't care what color you are (or what "decent" you're from), and neither do the fans.  I just don't get this US obsession with race.

Comment: @StephenG to be fair, that is offering two choices: i) white OR ii) of European descent. That doesn't actually imply that all Europeans are white. In fact, it does the exact opposite: it is clearly separating "white" from "European", just offering both in the same option. Which actually does make some sense since it makes a cultural grouping and not a racial one.

Comment: *this list may have sense in US, but not in Europe.* - even in the States the distinction between the terms Latina/o and Hispanic is reasonably well understood, see https://www.vox.com/2015/8/19/9173457/hispanic-latino-comic for a primer on how the words are used there.  So the survey should look broken even from a US point of view.  Even the [2010 US census](https://www.census.gov/2010census/pdf/2010_Questionnaire_Info.pdf) didn't treat hispanic/latino/latina as a race, it just asked, *Is Person X of Hispanic, Latino, or Spanish origin?*

Comment: @dbc when I was young spanish press told me at USA the most of student answered Spain is a region of Mexico on a survey. It is known a quote (I don't remember what general) "God created war so the americans learn geography". This would have have had sense on 20th century and a US context, I should have say. No sense in XXI century

Comment: I think for Asian people is worst. East Asia, Center Asia? that's a race? ask it to a uigur. arabian is not even mentioned where arabians have historical studies on mathematics (this is mathematics on a computer)

Comment: They also lumped together Native American, Pacific Islanders and Indigenous Australians together, even though they're on the opposite sides of the planet

Comment: So, basically, this question has been put together by amateurs who appear to have a spectacularly weak grasp of any of the Social Sciences which discuss geo-cultural identity?

Comment: So now it's a different question for different people taking the survey - and the questions are adjusted as answers come in and outside feeback is posted. This will make for splendidly valid statistics!

Answer (score 31):

As this whole situation recently (since the CoC update) has shown, they aren't just Americacentric, they are Silicon-Vallycentric. As James Damore [pointed out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google%27s_Ideological_Echo_Chamber), this type of thinking isn't specific to SO.

The staff have to remember that not only do ~50% of people in their own country not have the same political/social views as them, this gap is likely to widen when you consider their global reach.

SO currently wants maximum diversity, so long as you agree with their definition of diversity. Diversity of thought is not welcome in the People's Democratic Republic of Stack Overflow (PDRSO, which I now refer to it by to reflect their blatant suppression of any dissenting thought and opinion).

Comment: Plot twist: China actually owns SE, via some sock puppet companies. :D

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard: Does it really?

Comment: @MikeS159: I see it on some US media, and from US politicians, few of which are from Silicon Valley.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica - Let's just hope that Pipe Piper and/or Genaro Network doesn't have ownership into Stack Exchange.  Anyone who saw the series finale will understand this comment.

Comment: But Stack Exchange is not routed in Silicon Valley at all. None of the founders or first employees have worked at a typical Silicon Valley company, big or small (though Jeff Atwood worked in California, it never had any significant influence). It is more of an online company with a bias towards Microsoft (not in Silicon Valley), though there is a sense of it becoming more or more New York centric. But New York is not Silicon Valley.

Comment: Jeff Atwood [worked at a small Microsoft consultancy](https://www.wired.com/2012/07/stackoverflow-jeff-atwood/) before becoming a full-time blogger and later co founded Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 13):

**In fact, in my own country, racist questions like this are one of the biggest taboos.**

Yes it seems like the height of rudeness to me -- species, gender, nationality, marital status, and age, are all "protected" classifications.

You might forgive it in a government census, possibly not though.

Somebody's place of birth even is something a friend might tell you -- and it's warm, or very uncool, to ask.

You might as well make allowances for American sensibilities too, though -- if 'they' are at home with that kind of bureaucracy then, live and let live -- it's not like everybody is obliged to take part in it I guess.

Part of my objection I suppose it's that it's such a horrific question that it could bias the rest of the survey -- whatever else they're trying to ask will only be answered by people who are willing to answer that -- which (bias) makes the survey worthless IMO but then I'm not the person asking and I don't know why they are asking, maybe it helps someone to "check some boxes" somewhere.