# Update wording in subject of automated "100k reputation" email

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reputation, email, email-notification

I recently received an automated email from @juan.garza of the Community Management Team.

### Subject: Bicycles Stack Exchange — You're killing it.

Now my immediate thought was ***"what have I done wrong?"***   but no, I'd hit 100k points and this was a positive thing.

Perhaps this is a cultural, age, regional jargon thing but "killing it" isn't a positive statement globally.

Also, there are several SE sites where "killing it" could be taken wrong - parenting, martial arts, ukrainian-language, pets, latin, and any other language SE site.

SUGGESTION: can that text be updated to "you've hit a significant milestone" or "congratulations on hitting 100k rep" or something completely unambiguous.

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I'm sure this is an American-ism. My first thought was that I didn't see anything wrong with it because I was looking for a typo before I realized this is probably weird to non-Americans, and probably super confusing to non-native English speakers.

Comment: While this is being updated, Juan Garza (better known as [Juan M](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/296470/juan-m)) appears to have left the CM team.

Comment: He left quite some time back, so yeah, that needs updating too, as does the process here, though hopefully cm attrition should be minimal hopefully?

Comment: I just realised it is conceivable for someone to get "Buddhism SE - you're killing it"   which is not in-line with the teachings therein.

Comment: I had an urge to add "You're killing it" to the title of this meta question...

Comment: Millennials are killing Stack Exchange!

Comment: Subject: "... You're killing it.";  Footer: "<3" haha

Comment: I remember having the same reaction. I don't think it's necessarily just a non-native vs native US thing, though for the record, English isn't my first language either.

Comment: @tripleee one might say that English isn't the first/native language of Americans either - they're divergent dialects only drawn back toward each other by technology like radio then movies then TV etc.

Comment: Same with the 250k email. Also, no news about the swag several months after receiving it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. After review, we've decided not to send this email for now, and it's been turned off. We came to the conclusion that a form email is not the way we really want to be thanking our contributors for reaching this milestone.

The original intent of this email was to provide you with a link where you could claim a T-shirt, some stickers, and/or misc. swag for reaching the rep threshold. Swag, including merch for reaching specific reputation thresholds, [is currently on pause](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/swag-is-coming-back-temporarily-paused). The email was retained because we still wanted to acknowledge the amount of time and effort that is required to reach the threshold.

In the interim, we'll be doing our best to send something a bit more personal to folks who reach these milestones.

Comment: Swag?   SWAG !!??  You have my attention!